# How make a paragraph in blank or a better spacing?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

How can I leave a paragraph completely blank or a larger spacing only between two specific lines of my document? I want to separate the words "inicial" and "Para" through a completely blank line or better spacing.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,indice]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Calcule o valor do fluxo do campo magn\'{e}tico que atravessa a espira nessa 
situa\c{c}\~{a}o inicial.
Para uma melhor perce\c{c}\~{a}o do problema
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want a new paragraph starting at "Para"?

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen I want a paragraph in blank between the words "inicial" and "Para".

Comment: Do you mean `...inicial. <blank line>\medskip<blank line>Para...`?

Comment: @egreg Is there any line spacing that is larger than this?

Comment: You can use `\vspace{5cm}`, for instance

Comment: @Denis Thanks. It's what I was looking for.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Why would you want it to be bigger? There is `\bigskip`, but the idea is to make a break, not to leave a big white strip across the page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was solved in the comments.